# How can I send get request directly to an API?

Tags: json, get

I sniffed the network traffic coming out of an app that displays real time data. I am trying to get access to the api to display the same real time data on a website that I am working on currently. I was able to view the get request and the response using fiddler and I then sent a get request directly using the url. However, my get request was blocked by CORs policy. I'm a beginner and would like to know how to access the API.

Answer (score 0):

If the server that's hosting the API doesn't supply COR headers that explicitly allow this, you're not going to be able to make these requests via your browser. I'd recommend making the requests on your server instead of in the browser, because that's not bound by CORs settings.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer! I don't really understand the terms haha as this is the first time I am trying to access an API. I am working on a website using react and sent a get request directly from my react front end. What can I do differently?

Comment: Do you have a back end? e.g. Node/C#/PHP/Etc? the request is being made by the browser, which won't be allowed. The flow should be:

React app makes request to YOUR server

Your server makes request to API

Your server returns data to the react app

Display data in react app.